# Domain forwarding in MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos

I need `some.domain.com:8000` to be linked to `162.251.150.150:80`.

So when I load `some.domain.com:8000` in my browser - an actual request should be going to `162.251.150.150:80`.

I was trying to use `pf.conf` for that with different settings, but without success:

```
pass out proto tcp from  some.domain.com port 8000 to 162.251.150.150 port 80
nat pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to some.domain.com port 8000 -> 162.251.150.150 port 80
```

(I've created an alias for `some.domain.com` in hosts file along with that)

I have MacOS `10.12.3`

p.s. I made that working in Ubuntu with following command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -d some.domain.com  -j DNAT --to-destination 162.251.150.150:80
```

p.p.s. I saw following question

[What is the modern way to do port-forwarding on El Capitan? (forward port 80 to 8080)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230300/what-is-the-modern-way-to-do-port-forwarding-on-el-capitan-forward-port-80-to)

My question is specific because of domain name need to be specified

Comment: Related and almost duplicate: [Murus firewall - redirect an ip to localhost web server](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267127/murus-firewall-redirect-an-ip-to-localhost-web-server). If you have questions or don't get this to work make a comment @klanomath here and I will write an answer.

Comment: @klanomath tried 


`rdr pass log on lo0 proto tcp from en1 to 10.0.0.1 port 8000 -> 162.251.150.150 port 80`

`pass out on en1 route-to lo0 proto tcp from en1 to 10.0.0.1 port 8000 keep state`
with some.domain.com linked to 10.0.0.1 in hosts file - didn't work.
Could you please help me?
(edited - didn't finish comment)

Comment: Tried and doesn't work for you?

Comment: @klanomath sorry, just finished comment, please see above